# Do $q.all resolve before the $http request from a service?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service where I make some http calls. I'd like to use $q.all to show a message after all calls are ended. However the message is shown before the ajax calls are sent. Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/xgIlCyQPadOrwHCP5HJj?p=preview

```
  var request1 = function(){return reportService.getReport("data.json",1,1)},

  request2 = function(){return reportService.getReport("data2.json",2,2)},

  request3 = function(){return reportService.getReport("data3.json",3,3)}

  $q.all([request1(),request2(),request3()]).then(console.log("All Done!!"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a callback in the $q.all, not direct call to console.log

```
 $q.all([request1(),request2(),request3()]).then(function(){
    console.log("fatto")

  });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this would be an interceptor.

You could keep track of what calls are made and what responses have been resolved.  Based on this you could display messages by broadcasting on the rootscope and then showing messages based on those broadcasts.

Here is an example of an interceptor that broadcasts 'open_requests' when there are open requests and then 'all_requests_done' when all the requests are finished:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope){    
    var numLoadings = 0;    
    return {
        request: function (config) {    
            numLoadings++;

            $rootScope.$broadcast("open_requests");
            return config || $q.when(config)

        },
        response: function (response) {    
            if ((--numLoadings) === 0) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("all_requests_done");
            }

            return response || $q.when(response);    
        },
        responseError: function (response) {    
            if (!(--numLoadings)) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("all_requests_done");
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };
})
.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Seems a good solution, however this will intercept all ajax requests, not only the request from my service. Is this right?

Comment: Yes but if you look at the config object, you can figure out what url the request came from and based on that you can determine if it is a request you are interested in.  This is how I put loaders on my screen.  Like if I have 3 widgets and they all require a call to the server, I can broadcast 'widget_1_loading', 'widget_1_loaded', 'widget_2_loaded' etc.. based on inspecting the url in the config object.  I can then react accordingly by displaying 3 loaders and showing/hiding them on the correct widget.

Comment: Could you explain how I "can figure out what url the request came from and based on that I can determine if it is a request I'm interested in"? I don't know much about interceptors...

Comment: for interceptors there are 3 scenarios, a request, a response, or an error is intercepted.  This is represented by the request, response, responseError methods.  Try doing a console.log(config) in those methods.  The config object will contain the url that the request/response/error came from.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var request1 = function(){
      var deferred=$q.defer();
   deferred.resolve(reportService.getReport("data.json",1,1));
   return deferred.promise;
  },

request2 = 
function(){
var deferred=$q.defer();              
 deferred.resolve(reportService.getReport("data2.json",2,2));
 return deferred.promise;

 },

  request3 = function(){
 var deferred=$q.defer(); 

 deferred.resolve(reportService.getReport("data3.json",3,3));
 return deferred.promise;
 }

 return $q.all([request1(),request2(),request3()]).then(console.log("All Done!!"));
```

Comment: $http return a promise. Why I should use deferred/promise here?

Comment: In the angular latest version without use of deferred it throws error some times when getting data from server. So we use deferred promise pattern frnd...

Comment: However if one calls fails, the fail callback function are immediately fired?